# Pivotal Web Services server encoding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I deployed Spring Boot app on Pivotal Web Services, everything works fine, but when I try to create content in my app with cyrillic, the encoding is broken. I use ClearDb Mysql, but on db level everything is encoded correctly, encoding of Db is UTF-8, but when I try to create content with my app, cyrillic is not encoded. Is this problem on server level and how to configure server to use UTF-8 encoding? Thanks in advance.
P.P.S The server on Pivotal Web Services is Tomcat.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you're seeing the encoding fail?  Is this in HTML/JSON output generated by your application?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: When I seed db manually with cyrillic characters, the fetched data from db is showing in HTML without encoding issues. But for example, if i fill data in a form, the data is not encoded properly and its saved in db as unknown symbols.

Comment: This is generally something your app should be handling.  See here -> https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.  If you set this up correctly in your HTML, the rest should just work. If it doesn't, try to break the issue down more.  Look at Chrome Dev tools and confirm the browser is sending the request encoded properly.  Try logging the data to confirm your app receives it correctly.  Manually pull data from the DB and confirm it was saved properly.  Log data after it's read from the DB to confirm it's read correctly.  Check the encoding of the display HTML.